# The column name 'phoneNumber' is specified more than once in the SET clause

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am creating for my student project, a coffee shop online.

As it is a big file and, I am not sure which part anyone would need, here is a [github link](https://github.com/ItzikFekete/DatabaseMVC)

I have created a Registration form and I have created a order form.

When I try to register, I get this error on the second page

The full message error is: 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: The column name 'phoneNumber' is specified more than once in the SET clause or column list of an INSERT. A column cannot be assigned more than one value in the same clause. Modify the clause to make sure that a column is updated only once. If this statement updates or inserts columns into a view, column aliasing can conceal the duplication in your code.

Source Error:

Line 164:
Line 165:                };
**Line 166:                var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);**
Line 167:                if (result.Succeeded)
Line 168:                {

The full log is below:

> [SqlException (0x80131904): The column name 'phoneNumber' is specified
>   more than once in the SET clause or column list of an INSERT. A column
>   cannot be assigned more than one value in the same clause. Modify the
>   clause to make sure that a column is updated only once. If this
>   statement updates or inserts columns into a view, column aliasing can
>   conceal the duplication in your code.]
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception,
>   Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) +212
>
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException
>   exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) +81
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose) +630
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior,
>   SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream,
>   BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj, Boolean& dataReady) +4222
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds,
>   RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString, Boolean
>   isInternal, Boolean forDescribeParameterEncryption) +261
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.CompleteAsyncExecuteReader(Boolean
>   isInternal, Boolean forDescribeParameterEncryption) +254
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalEndExecuteNonQuery(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult, String endMethod, Boolean isInternal) +651
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.EndExecuteNonQueryInternal(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +245
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.EndExecuteNonQueryAsync(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +151
>   System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult
>   iar, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, Task`1 promise, Boolean
>   requiresSynchronization) +86
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) +99
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) +61    System.Data.Entity.Utilities.CultureAwaiter`1.GetResult()
>   +38    System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.Update.Internal.d__0.MoveNext()
>   +2736    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) +99
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) +61
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.Update.Internal.d__0.MoveNext()
>   +398
>
> [UpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. See
>   the inner exception for details.]
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.Update.Internal.d__0.MoveNext()
>   +631    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) +99
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) +61
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.d__3d`1.MoveNext()
>   +743    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) +99
>
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) +61
>
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.<SaveChangesToStoreAsync>d__39.MoveNext()
>   +386    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) +99
>
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) +61
>
>   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.<ExecuteAsyncImplementation>d__9`1.MoveNext()
>   +348    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) +99
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) +61
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.d__31.MoveNext()
>   +802
>
> [DbUpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. See
>   the inner exception for details.]
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) +99
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) +61
>   Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.d__5a.MoveNext()
>   +217    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) +99
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) +61
>   Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.d__16.MoveNext()
>   +250    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) +99
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) +61    Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.CultureAwaiter.GetResult() +35 
>   Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.d__0.MoveNext() +1126
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) +99
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) +61    Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.d__d.MoveNext()
>   +550    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) +99
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) +61    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
>   +28    registrationLogin.Controllers.<Register>d__15.MoveNext() in C:\Users\Itzik
>   Private\Documents\GitHub\DatabaseMVC\registrationLogin\registrationLogin\Controllers\AccountController.cs:166
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) +99
>
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) +61
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.TaskAsyncActionDescriptor.EndExecute(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +97
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass8_0.<BeginInvokeAsynchronousActionMethod>b__1(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +17
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +10
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +32
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__11_0()
>   +50    System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass11_1.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__2()
>   +228    System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass7_0.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__1(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +10
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +34
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass3_6.<BeginInvokeAction>b__3()
>   +35    System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass3_1.<BeginInvokeAction>b__5(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +100
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +10
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +27
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.<>c.<BeginExecuteCore>b__152_1(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +11
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +29
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +45
>   System.Web.Mvc.<>c.<BeginExecute>b__151_2(IAsyncResult asyncResult,
>   Controller controller) +13
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +22
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +26
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +10
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.<>c.<BeginProcessRequest>b__20_1(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +28
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +29
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>   +28    System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult
>   result) +9
>   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.InvokeEndHandler(IAsyncResult ar)
>   +152    System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.OnAsyncHandlerCompletion(IAsyncResult
>   ar) +126

Comment: why didn't you just post the query? this is not helpfull at all

Comment: debug your application. I'd also do a full text search for the string "phoneNumber", case sensitive and whole-word only, and then in the find results the double mention should be obvious.

Comment: @sLowDowN i'd tell him to slow down before posting... -_-

Comment: On a side note. Do not check in `bin` and `obj` folders, there's no point in checking in anything which is generated.

Comment: For some reason your `title` migration has references to both `phoneNumber` and `PhoneNumber` both being changed to different types on `AspNetUsers`.

Comment: ^ yeah. once it was a string, then it became an int (for a phone number, using string is recommended for several reasons). please also look up the current schema (table definition) of the AspNetUsers table directly in your SQL server database.

Answer (score 3):

The error is quite obvious, you try to use an insert query but specify the `phone number` column twice in the command:

***The column name 'phoneNumber' is specified more than once in the SET clause or column list of an INSERT.***

Review your query again and eliminate the double conflict, it will resolve your issue.

Comment: @Itzik then post the query if you want help. It's not rocket science.

Comment: I have the same problem but it raises from bulkcopy. Then, what's the main problem? there is a csv file and I'm just trying to bulkcopy it to a table.

Answer (score 2):

The exception is basically says that you have specified `phoneNumber` more than once in SET clause, when inserting values to your table, i.e.

```
INSERT INTO TestTable(Id, Name, phoneNumber, Age, phoneNumber)
SELECT * FROM BLABLA
```

notice double `phoneNumber` after `Name` and `Age`.

Answer (score 2):

Check your data binding or mapping, you might accidentally bind/map different control or field with the same column. Another possibility is that you are using the same variable name to refer to a control or field. I am using alpha anywhere software, I get the same problem and I managed to solve it after fixing the data binding and change the variable name. Might have a little difference but the root could be the same. Hope this help!!

Answer (score 1):

Check your file .
It may have multiple enter CRLF in one record for same person .Sometime people have multiple phone number and it may be separated with , In a csv file .Just count commas divide by line if its even you are good. One of your line has extra comma so last column is getting repeated.
Find person who has two numbers.
Other way is divide file in two small pieces like 10 small files load one by one  you will see atleast one of them will fail then split failing file again and keep doing so .

Answer (score 0):

For EFCore 6, it errored out on me because of the incorrect foreign key column name casing. It was fixed when I changed "companyid" to "CompanyId".

```
public int? CompanyId { get; set; }

[ForeignKey("companyid")]
public virtual Company Company { get; set; }
```